# Using $A.createComponent to load a Lightning App Page

Tags: lightning-aura-components

Is it possible to use $A.createComponent() in load an existing Lightning App Page? If so what would be the syntax for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, $A.createComponent can only create components, not entire app pages. You would want to move the app logic to a component, or just navigate to the page using its' URL.

Comment: Is there a way I could wrap the Lightning App Page in a component? Or would that be the same as using $A.createComponent() in the first place?

Comment: @John_Henry You can't put an app in a component. You'll need to refactor so that your app's logic is in a component.